# Can a Facebook Page Tab app determine which Facebook ad the user clicked on to get there?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

If a user ends up looking at a Facebook Page Tab app as a result of clicking on a Facebook ad, is there any way for the app to know which ad the user clicked?

To explain a bit further:

I have a very simple Facebook app, which consists of a single static HTML page. This page contains a link to a form on another site.

The app is meant to be used as a Page Tab. So it will live on a Facebook page, at a URL similar to this one:

https://www.facebook.com/pages/My-Page-Name/1234?sk=app_5678

Now: I will be running a Facebook ad campaign, consisting of several different ads. Each of these ads will link to the URL above, but they will contain different messaging (e.g., different text copy, different images, etc.).

I would like to know which of these ads produces the most conversions (where a "conversion" is defined as successfully submitting the form).

So the user flow is something like this:

1. User sees an ad on Facebook and clicks on it
2. User goes to the Page Tab on Facebook containing the app in an iframe **(here's where I'm stuck: how can I pass a value the into the iframe that uniquely identifies the ad that was clicked on?)**
3. User clicks on the link in the app, taking them to the offsite page with the form
4. User fills out the form (converts)

In a more traditional scenario, I would just add Google Analytics querystring variables to the URLs that the ads link to:

- https://www.facebook.com/pages/My-Page-Name/1234?sk=app_5678&ad_version=a
- https://www.facebook.com/pages/My-Page-Name/1234?sk=app_5678&ad_version=b
- etc.

However, because my app lives in an iframe, cross-domain rules prevent it from accessing the parent URL.

I looked at [the documentation for Facebook's JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript), thinking that Facebook might expose something useful there, but no luck.

Does Facebook provide a way to track this kind of thing (or are there any clever workarounds)? Or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the app_data query string param as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs#integrating

Comment: For other readers: my ads will link to URLs like https://www.facebook.com/pages/My-Page-Name/1234?sk=app_5678&app_data=unique_ad_identifier_here. Then, my app will use Facebook's PHP SDK to retrieve and parse the signed_request that Facebook passes in. app_data will be part of that signed_request, and from there I can do whatever I need with it (in this case, inserting it as a utm_content querystring variable in the link to the form.)